# Google indexing user profile pages of my website

Tags: seo

I have a linkedIn like website. I need Google index each public profile pages.
Few things in my mind.
1- Since there is no user listing on my page. And also I dont want to show all profile listing on the website.
How google will index all profile pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to make a list accessible for everyone, you should probably make a sitemap.xml that Google can read. If you are using Webmaster Tools you could tell Google your URL to it, and they will index all URLs.

Read more about sitemaps here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

Comment: and how to prevent that xml not to be accessible by public?

Comment: If that is a concern, I guess it also should be a concern that all profiles are listed on Google? You could just search for "Site:www.yoursite.com" on Google to see all indexed pages. But apart from that, I guess the easiest approach is to name the sitemap to something weird and not guessable, and add that to Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: Right, Suppose my xml url is "mysite.com/sitemap8888890.xml. I submit sitemap8888890.xml to google for indexing and google show this xml link on the search result page. How to prevent it?

Comment: Google won't index the actual XML, but the content of it.

Comment: Thank you. Last and final thing. What if I create a php file to return the xml string? Is it valid. Or I need to write a cron job to write the xml to the disc?

Comment: It's valid, but it should output valid XML data. So be sure to use right doctype and content type. Like so: header('Content-type: text/xml');